# Changing word doc into pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, doc

Is there a way to convert .doc file to .pdf keeping the format same as doc file which can also include images?

I am able to generate PDF file from doc but only the text appears.

Comment: Posting the code you already have would help.

Comment: What do you hope to gain by converting Word docs to PDF?

Comment: Universal compatibility maybe !

Comment: Have you resolved your problem ?

Comment: So, have you fixed your problem ? Accept one answer ;)

Comment: Youu can try http://www.dancrintea.ro/doc-to-pdf/
it works very well on doc files (but not on docx).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a library based on Open-Office.
It allows to convert from (and to) all the formats supported by OpenOffice.

Moreover, if your doc is read correctly by OpenOffice, it should be converted exactly as you see.

I know [JOD Converter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) for **exemple** :

```
File inputFile = new File("document.doc");
File outputFile = new File("document.pdf");

// connect to an OpenOffice.org instance running on port 8100
OpenOfficeConnection connection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(8100);
connection.connect();

// convert
DocumentConverter converter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(connection);
converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile);

// close the connection
connection.disconnect();
```

You can also use a simple command line (with oo installed) :

```
#!/bin/sh 
DIR=$(pwd) 
DOC=$DIR/$1 
echo "Doc to convert : $DOC"
/user/bin/oowriter-invisible "macro://Standard.Module1.ConvertWordToPDF($DOC)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to read the doc file and then [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to write the pdf file.

Comment: Converting is not a problem, but keeping the format of pdf same as doc file and also include image/logo from doc file to pdf.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Openoffice Macro** for export doc as pdf like,

```
sub Docaspdf  

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------  
rem define variables  
dim document   as object  
dim dispatcher as object  

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------  
rem get access to the document  
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame  
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")  

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------  
dim args1(2) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue  
args1(0).Name = "URL"  
args1(0).Value = "file:///C:/doc.pdf"  
args1(1).Name = "FilterName"  
args1(1).Value = "writer_pdf_Export"  
args1(2).Name = "FilterData"  
args1(2).Value = Array(Array("UseLosslessCompression",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("Quality",0,90,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ReduceImageResolution",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("MaxImageResolution",0,300,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("UseTaggedPDF",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("SelectPdfVersion",0,0,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ExportNotes",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ExportBookmarks",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("OpenBookmarkLevels",0,-1,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("UseTransitionEffects",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("IsSkipEmptyPages",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("IsAddStream",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("EmbedStandardFonts",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("FormsType",0,0,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ExportFormFields",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("AllowDuplicateFieldNames",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("HideViewerToolbar",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("HideViewerMenubar",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("HideViewerWindowControls",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ResizeWindowToInitialPage",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("CenterWindow",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("OpenInFullScreenMode",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("DisplayPDFDocumentTitle",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("InitialView",0,0,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("Magnification",0,0,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("Zoom",0,100,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("PageLayout",0,0,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("FirstPageOnLeft",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("InitialPage",0,1,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("Printing",0,2,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("Changes",0,4,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("EnableCopyingOfContent",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("EnableTextAccessForAccessibilityTools",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ExportLinksRelativeFsys",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("PDFViewSelection",0,0,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ConvertOOoTargetToPDFTarget",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ExportBookmarksToPDFDestination",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("_OkButtonString",0,"",com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("EncryptFile",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("PreparedPasswords",0,,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("RestrictPermissions",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("PreparedPermissionPassword",0,Array(),com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("",0,,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE))  

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:ExportToPDF", "", 0, args1())  
end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import officetools.OfficeFile; 

FileInputStream(new File("test.doc"));  
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.pdf")); /

OfficeFile f = new OfficeFile(fis,"localhost","8100", false);
```

convert to pdf

```
f.convert(fos,"pdf");
```

Comment: If you mentioned the origin of the `officetools`, your answer would be more valuable.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx) to [convert Doc files to PDF](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/howto-convert-a-document-to-pdf.html). This component retains the format of the word document when converted to PDF. It also converts the images along with text.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.